# useEffect não atualizando estados na primeira iteração

Tags: react, react-hooks

Estou utilizando o useEffect para fazer um get dos dados de uma tabela. O problema é que mesmo recebendo os dados da api os estados não são atualizados na primeira iteração fazendo com que eu tenha que fazer dois get na api toda vez que troco de pagina ou aplico um filtro. Há algo que possa fazer que faça com que os estados sejam atualizados na primeira iteração?

```
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getData(){
           try {
                const response = await axios.get(url, {
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('user_token')
                    }
                });
                console.log(response);
                setNextPage(response.data.next);
                setPrevPage(response.data.previous)
                setPageResults(response.data.results);
                setCount(response.data.count);
                setMount(0);
                console.log(pageResults);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('Erro:', error);
            } 
        }

        getData();

    }, [mount]);
```

Primeira iteração:

[image: Primeira iteração]

Segunda iteração:

[image: Segunda iteração]

useStates utilizados como pedido nos comentários abaixo:

```
    const [url, setUrl] = useState(defaultUrl);
    const [mount, setMount] = useState(1);
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
    const [nameSearch, setNameSearch]= useState("");
    const [citySearch, setCitySearch] = useState("");
    const [stateSearch, setStateSearch] = useState("");
    const [minAgeSearch, setMinAgeSearch] = useState(0);
    const [maxAgeSearch, setMaxAgeSearch] = useState(100);
    const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(20);
    const [nextPage, setNextPage] = useState("");
    const [prevPage, setPrevPage] = useState("");
    const [pageResults, setPageResults]= useState([]);
```

Comment: Já experimentou retirar o mount do segundo argumento do useEffect? E também posta os useState que vc está criando.

Comment: já, torna-se um loop infinito. Além disso, continua a atualizar o estado apenas na segunda iteração. Quanto aos useState, fiz uma edição a pergunta, os adicionando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precisa ser colocado no `useEffect` um `array` sem nenhum item, ou seja, `[]`, e isso tem o efeito no momento que o componente for criado o método é invocado(`componentDidMount()` se fosse classe), exemplo do código funcionando:

```js
function Root() {
  const [obj, setObj] = React.useState([]);
  function getDataAsync() {
      const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=100';
      fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {        
          setObj(response.results);
        })
  }
  React.useEffect(() => {
    getDataAsync();
  }, []); 
  if (obj.length === 0) {
    return <h4>{'Carregando ...'}</h4>;
  } else {
    return (
      <ul>
        {
          obj.map(item => (
            <li key={item.login.uuid}>
              {item.login.username}
            </li>
          ))
        }
      </ul>
    )  
 }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Root/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Aguarde ...</div>
```

Eu prefiro criar o método sempre fora e chamar dentro do `useEffect`, mas, se for criado dentro também funciona.