# Propriedade vindo como undefined?

Tags: javascript, ajax, react, axios

Quando tento acessar a propriedade full_name do objeto user com useState, a aplicação diz que a propriedade está undefined.

Aqui está o código:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import api from '../../services/api'

function User(props) {

const [user, setUser] = useState({})
const { id } = props.match.params

useEffect(() => {
  async function getUser() {
    const response = await api.get(`/users/${id}`)
    setUser(response.data)
}
getUser()
}, [id])

console.log(user.repos.full_name[0])

function User() {

return (
    <div>
        {user.name}

    </div>
)

}

export default Use
```

e aqui está o erro:

```
index.js:1 The above error occurred in the <User> component:
in User (created by Context.Consumer)
in Route (at Routes.js:13)
in Switch (at Routes.js:10)
in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
in BrowserRouter (at Routes.js:9)
in Routes (at App.js:9)
in App (at src/index.js:5)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling 
behavior.
Visit https://fb.me/react-error-boundaries to learn more about error 
boundaries.
```

Comment: Entendi sim, muito obrigado pela ajuda, estava tentando a bastante tempo, eu não tinha me atentado a isso, mas com certeza estudarei mais...

Comment: No seu componente você utiliza as propriedades do esto user sem se atentar se ele realmente já foi carregado com as informações da API. Isso gera estes problemas com `undefined`.

No seu código no primeiro carregamento do componente, ele tentará acessar estas propriedades e irá falhar, pois ainda não terá obtido a resposta da API e então inflado o estado `user`. Verificar a existência dos dados no seu estado antes de os usar é importante em códigos assíncronos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bastante pessoas vem com a mesma duvida, no seu caso na `props` a informação não tem um estado local então o seu código no `array` do `useEffect` pode ser sem nenhum item, para que o mesmo seja executado na criação do componente, exemplo:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import api from '../../services/api'

function User(props) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        const { id } = props.match.params
        async function getUser() {
            const response = await api.get(`/users/${id}`)
            setUser(response.data)
        }
        getUser()
    }, []); 
    if (user) {
        return (
            <div>
                {user.name}
            </div>
        )
    } else {
        return (<div>Carregando ...</div>);
    }
}

export default User
```

Seu código também tem erros conceituais, precisa dar uma lida na documentação, mas, acho que com as minhas alterações resolva e tire suas duvidas, não entendi porque você chamou a classe dentro dela mesma, com certeza falta dar uma estudada.

Outro exemplo:

- [useEffect não atualizando estados na primeira iteração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/432462/useeffect-n%c3%a3o-atualizando-estados-na-primeira-itera%c3%a7%c3%a3o/432491#432491)